# Highlight a text displayed in eclipse editor area programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, string, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a eclipse plugin in which i need to open up a text file in eclipse editor and highlight a line inside the file programatically.

To open a file and to highlight a text/line in eclipse editor area, i used below code,

```
fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(file.toURI());
page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore);
editor.selectAndReveal(startOffset, endOffset);
```

Now say i have a file with below contents

```
Line:1         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Line:2         yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
:
:
Line: 20       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Line: 21       bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Now i need to highlight Line:20 in above file. For that i need to start offset and end offset of that line. How can i achieve this in Java?

Thanks in advance.